# Extract ARIMA object from list and store in dataframe in R

Tags: r, apply, arima

My goal is to run ARIMA for multiple time series and store result in dataframe. Here is my example:

```
library(forecast)

my_df <- data.frame(gr  = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10)), 
                    val = sample(1:100, 20))

get_arima <- function(sample_name = NA,df = NA){
  fit = auto.arima(df[df$gr == sample_name, ]$val)
  return(fit)
}

result <- sapply(c("a", "b"), get_arima, df = my_df, simplify = F)
result_df <- data.frame(gr = names(result), 
  model_result = unlist(result, use.names =  F))
```

It produces the following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("forecast_ARIMA", "ARIMA", "Arima")’ to a data.frame
```

The goal is to have ARIMA model in the second column so that I do something like this `forecast(result_df$model_result, h=3)`

I am guessing that there are probably multiple ways to do it, but I would appreciate answer with `apply` and getting results from list into dataframe.

Comment: The model output is a `list`.  What do you want as output `lapply(result, `[[`, "fitted")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model output is a `list`

```
str(result[[1]])
#List of 18
# $ coef     : Named num 54.3
#  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "intercept"
# $ sigma2   : num 1454
# $ var.coef : num [1, 1] 131
# ...
```

and 'result' is a `list` as well. If we are keeping the model as a column in the 'data.frame', then keep it as `list`

---

```
df1 <- data.frame(gr = names(result), model_result = I(result))
```

With `tibble`, we can directly create a `list` column without any `I`

```
library(tibble)
df1 <- tibble(gr = names(result), model_result = result)
df1
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   gr    model_result
#  <chr> <named list>
#1 a     <ARIMA>     
#2 b     <ARIMA>
```

Extract each element with `[[`

```
df1$model_result[[1]]
#Series: df[df$gr == sample_name, ]$val 
#ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

#Coefficients:
#         mean
#      54.3000
#s.e.  11.4378

#sigma^2 estimated as 1454:  log likelihood=-50.07
#AIC=104.14   AICc=105.86   BIC=104.75
```

and apply the `forecast`

```
forecast::forecast( df1$model_result[[1]], h = 3)
#Point Forecast    Lo 80  Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
#11           54.3 5.439989 103.16 -20.42494 129.0249
#12           54.3 5.439989 103.16 -20.42494 129.0249
#13           54.3 5.439989 103.16 -20.42494 129.0249
```

If we want to get the `forecast` for all elements, use `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(df1$model_result, ~ forecast::forecast(.x, h = 3))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you help me to understand why do we need `I(result)` in dataframe? Can we just add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`? What type of other conversion (besides string as factor) does `data.frame` tries to perform on ARIMA object?

Comment: @user1700890 `I` stands for as is it.  It is only for a `list` column creation